# Difference of means -- Testing two algorithms

Tags: t-test, algorithms

I have to perform 2 tests of the difference of means for the results obtained by 2 learning algorithms.

**TEST 1**

1. I have 2 algorithms
2. I take a data set (with N examples)
3. I execute both algorithms 10 times
4. Each time, each algorithm is trained on a set of 9/10*N examples and tested against a set of N/10 examples (i.e. a 10-fold cross validation is done), and the result is a XX% value of correct classified examples in such a test set.

Here I use the t-test.
I know that the t-test makes assumptions of normality.
I use it because the data set is quite big ( N>100 ), so I can assume a normal distribution of data (and if data is normally distributed, the means of a single algorithm are normally distributed, and so the differences of the means of the two algorithsm are normally distributed). Or should I consider only N/10 as the sample size from which the means are drawn?

**TEST 2**

1. I have two algorithms
2. I take 10 instances of a combinatorial optimization problem (a Travelling Salesman Problem)
3. I run each algorithm on the 10 instances
4. For each run, a write down the result value (that is at some distance from the optimal value for that instance)

How can I perform a test on the differences of means?
Which means can I consider?
Which data should I check for normality?

Answer (score 1):

For **TEST 1**, I gather the response variable is either *correct* or *incorrect*, that is, these are [Bernoulli trials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial).  For the [Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) / [Binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) distribution, the standard deviation is a function of the mean, thus you aren't estimating the standard deviation from your data in the same sense as a t-test.  So, in this case, you can use a [z-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test) for the difference of two proportions (see, the example in [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#Common_test_statistics)).  I don't know what software you're using, but if you were to test this in R, e.g.,  you would use [?prop.test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/prop.test.html).

For **TEST 2**, I think it's highly unlikely that the population underlying your data would be normally distributed, and with only 10 data, you wouldn't have enough for the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) to cover for you.  (Note that my reasoning here is a-priori; I think it usually doesn't make much sense to *test* for normality, and especially in this case with so few data, see: [Is normality testing essentially useless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/))  Instead, I would recommend you use the [Mann-Whitney U-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann-Whitney_U_test), which is a non-parametric analog of the t-test.  It would be appropriate if your data are not normal and your sample size is too small; it also can be more powerful than the t-test under these conditions.  In R, you would use [?wilcox.test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html).